# Is posible to write script that checks for differences between two patterns in configuration files

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

Linux. I have for example two config files.
First:

```
    criticalexceptions => [
    'yum-updatesd-helper: error',
    'cups: cupsd shutdown succeeded',
    'hda: drive_cmd: error',
    'end_request: I\/O error, dev fd0',
    'SAP[A-Z0-9]{3}_[0-9]{2}\[[0-9]+\]',
    'nrpe\[[0-9]+\]:',
    'collectd\[[0-9]+\]:',
    'kernel: cdrom: open failed',
    'gconfd.*Failed',
    'nrpe.*ERROR.*seteuid(0): Operation not permitted',
],
criticalpatterns => [
    'kernel: Kernel BUG',
    'error',
    'critical',
    'failed',
    'warning',
    'HACMP',
    'shutdown',
    'panic',
    'exiting',
],
```

and second

```
    criticalexceptions => [
    'as-ncs01 logger:',
    'logger: NetWorker media:',
    'warning while saving',
    'could not be opened and was not backed up',
    'NetWorker',
    'zmd:',
    'Succeeded with warning',
    'failed - POSSIBLE BREAKIN ATTEMPT!',
    'JBD: barrier-based sync failed on',
    'cmaeventd\[.*\]\: Logical drive [0-9] of Array Controller in slot',
    'end_request: I\/O error, dev fd0',
    'logrotate: error: unable to open \/var\/log\/sudosh',
    'logrotate: error: failed to rename \/var\/log\/sudosh',
    'smbd',
    'sap2.* winbindd\[\d{0,}\]\:   cli_rpc_pipe_open_schannel\: failed to get schannel session',
    'suse_register\[\d+\]:',
    'SAP[a-zA-Z0-9#]{3}_[0-9#]{2}\[[0-9]+\]',
    'nrpe\[[0-9]+\]:',
    'collectd\[[0-9]+\]:',
    'kernel: cdrom: open failed',
    'smartd\[[0-9]+\]:',
    'modprobe:.+Error inserting floppy',
    'saposcol\[[0-9]+\]:.+segfault at',
    'sapccm4x\[[0-9]+\]:.+segfault at',
    'XMLForm\[[0-9]+\]:',
    'sapxpg\[[0-9]+\]:',
    '\[Hardware Error\]: Machine check events logged',
    'snowagent:.+Could not parse time format', #9001208224

],
criticalpatterns => [
    'kernel: Kernel BUG',
    'error',
    'critical',
    'failed',
    'warning',
    'HACMP',
    'shutdown',
    'panic',
    'exiting',
    'link status definitely',
    'Link is (Down|Up)',
],
```

Is posible to write script that checks for differences between two patterns in this two configuration files?
[image: Screen with example]

Comment: Is the order of strings important?

Comment: I think not, is not important. Do You have any ideas?

Comment: Yes, sort the strings for each section and use `diff` or `comm`.

Comment: Please edit your question and add your desired output (no description) for that sample input.

Answer (score 0):

You've already got a side-by-side diff and it's unclear what you want the script to do.

Diffs aren't well equipped to deal with data like this, so the first thing you'll need to do is flatten it in a manner that makes each line descriptive of the structure. Then you can sort it and diff it.

```bash
flatten() {
  echo "$*"
  awk '
    /^\]/ { arr = "" }
    arr != "" && NF { sub(/^[[:space:]]+/, ""); print arr $0 }
    $2 $3 == "=>[" { arr = $1 $2 }
  ' "$@" |sort
}

gvimdiff <(flatten /tmp/a) <(flatten /tmp/b)
```

I've defined a `flatten` function that uses `awk` to flatten the data in your files. To remember what file we're on, the function prints the parameters (the file) at the top. Then we run `awk`. For lines that start with `]`, we've closed a structure. Empty the `arr` variable. If there is a non-empty `arr` variable and the line isn't blank (the number of fields is not zero), remove the leading white space and print it prefixed with the `arr` variable's contents. If the second and third fields concatenate to `=>[` then we've started an array. Save the array name and the `=>` in the `arr` variable. We then sort the output.

Now we can do a more informative diff. Rather than using temporary files, I'm using a bash technique to pipe the output of two flatten commands directly into `diff`.

I've run `gvimdiff` because that's my own go-to:

[image: gvimdiff output]

You could also run `diff -u <(flatten /tmp/a) <(flatten /tmp/b) |grep '^-'` to get your removed lines, etc.